# Do we have jquery selector using methods like $.id('header').childs('link').whenAttr('extra').all('a')

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Sometime I need to dynamically build a query selector string.But by using strings it looks ugly

```
$('#header>link[' + extraAttr + '] ' + childElement);
```

Nearly unreadable,hard to maintain.

So I wondering if there have any method-query api just let us to build a query like linq in .net

```
query = query.Where(xxx);
if(xxx){
     query.First(xxx);
}
return query;
```

Comment: I've been looking for a JS library that uses API functions instead of CSS selectors, too, but I don't think there is such a thing currently.

Comment: @RoToRa: Does the selectors API count as such an API function? ;)

Comment: @RoToRa Yeah,Seems I have to implement myself

Comment: @BoltClock The answer must be yes,I'm finding a way to keep them sync.I need to figure out how Sizzle works

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable names instead of hard-coding the values in the selector class names.

For especially your case, this could be a possible choice.

```
var children = $('#header').children('link'); // get the link children of header
var aElements = []; // create an empty array for expected a elements
$.each(children) function(index, obj) { // operate on each of the link elements
    if(($(obj).attr('extra')).length > 0) { // if the element has the attribute extra
        aElements.push($(obj.attr('class') + " a")); // push the a elements in its child to the array. Eventually the array will contain the list of all the desired 'a' elements.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this is what you wanted. Please let know if it was anything else.

Comment: You know jQuery has various kinds of selectors,but all of them must be written in a string.Image the old days how we handle the SQL statements,"Select "+ columns + " From Table Where "+conditions.Hard to maintain.I just wanna ask if there is any fluent selector api (or just a selector builder)to replace the selectors in string.There is a more complex example. '#data1 tr:nth-child(3) > td.err a[href^='http'] input:file' vs '$.f.id('data1').all('tr').nth(3).child('td').cls('err').all('a').attrStart('href','http').select()